# Python urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Tags: python, http, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to run a script to scrap news text from a site.

It seems that there is a restriction on scrapping after the homepage reorganization.

And I keep getting this error but if I test one sing url it works.

Any suggestions?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\park\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\bigkinds_headers_v1.3_20170522.py", line 157, in <module>
    result = fetch_news_detail(news['href'])  
  File "C:\Users\park\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\bigkinds_headers_v1.3_20170522.py", line 107, in fetch_news_detail
    res = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
  File "C:\Users\park\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\park\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\park\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\park\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\park\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\park\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

This is my code

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import urllib.parse
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
import random

def fetch_news_list(page, keyword,start,end):

    result = []

    url = "https://www.bigkinds.or.kr/news/newsResult.do"

    headers =  {
       'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13F69 Safari/601.1', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3', 'Accept-Encoding': 'none', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'
        }

    param = {
        'pageInfo':'newsResult',
        'login_chk':'null',
        'LOGIN_SN':'null',
        'LOGIN_NAME':'null',
        'indexName':'news',
        'keyword':keyword,
        'byLine':'',
        'searchScope':'1',
        'searchFtr':'1',
        'startDate':start,
        'endDate':end,
        'sortMethod':'date',
        'contentLength':'100',
        'providerCode':'',
        'categoryCode':'',
        'incidentCode':'',
        'dateCode':'',
        'highlighting':'',
        'sessionUSID':'',
        'sessionUUID':'test',
        'listMode':'',
        'categoryTab':'',
        'newsId':'',
        'filterProviderCode':'',
        'filterCategoryCode':'',
        'filterIncidentCode':'',
        'filterDateCode':'',
        'startNo':page,
        'resultNumber':'100',
        'topmenuoff':'',
        'resultState':'',
        'keywordJson':'{"searchDetailTxt1":keyword,"agreeDetailTxt1":"","needDetailTxt1":"","exceptDetailTxt1":"","o_id":"option1","startDate":start,"endDate":end,"providerNm":"","categoryNm":"","incidentCategoryNm":"","providerCode":"","categoryCode":"","incidentCategoryCode":"","searchFtr":"1","searchScope":"1","searchKeyword":"keyword"}',
        'keywordFilterJson':'',
        'totalCount':'',
        'interval':'',
        'quotationKeyword1':'',
        'quotationKeyword2':'',
        'quotationKeyword3':'',
        'searchFromUseYN':'N',
        'mainTodayPersonYn':'',
        'period':'1year'
        }

    param = urllib.parse.urlencode(param).encode() 

    req = urllib.request.Request(url, param, headers)
    sleepTime = random.randint(4,10)
    time.sleep(sleepTime)
    print(str(sleepTime) + ' seconds wait.')

    try :

        res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

    except URLError as e:
        if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
            print('We failed to reach a server.')
            print('Reason: ', e.reason)
        elif hasattr(e, 'code'):
            print('The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.')
            print('Error code: ', e.code)



    html = res.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    div_tags = soup.find_all('div', class_='resTxt')

    for cts in div_tags:

        ids = cts.find('h3')['id'][5:31]
        title = cts.find('h3',class_='list_newsId').get_text(strip=True)
        href = 'https://www.bigkinds.or.kr/news/detailView.do?docId=' + ids + '&returnCnt=1'

        sets = {
            'title' : title,
            'href' : href
            }

        result. append(sets)

    return result

def fetch_news_detail(url):
    result = {}
    res = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')

    responseJson = json.loads(res)       

    category = responseJson.get("detail").get("CATEGORY_MAIN")
    date = responseJson.get("detail").get("DATE")
    provider = responseJson.get("detail").get("PROVIDER")
    content = responseJson.get("detail").get("CONTENT")

    result = {
        'category': category,
        'date': date,
        'provider' : provider,
        'content': content
    }

    return result


keyword = input('(eg., 외국인 NOT(증시 OR 순매수 OR 증권 OR 코스피 OR 코스닥 OR 주식 OR 주가 OR 투타 OR KBO OR 야구 OR KBL OR 농구 OR 축구 OR 올림픽 OR K리그))\n input word: ')
start = input('(eg., 2017-01-01)\n input startday: ')
end = input('(eg., 2017-02-01)\n input endday: ')

page = 1
count = 1
flag = True  

f = open('bigkinds.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')

while True:
    if not flag:
        break

    news_list = fetch_news_list(page, keyword,start,end) 
    sleepTime = random.randint(3,8)
    time.sleep(sleepTime)
    print(str(sleepTime) + ' seconds wait.')

    for news in news_list:
        result = fetch_news_detail(news['href']) 

        result['title'] = news['title']

        f.write('==' * 40 + '\n')
        f.write('category: ' + result['category'] + '\n')
        f.write('title: ' + result['title'] + '\n')
        f.write('date: ' + result['date'] + '\n')
        f.write('provider: ' + result['provider'] + '\n')
        f.write('content: ' + result['content'] + '\n')
        f.write('==' * 40 + '\n')

        count += 1
        if count >=5002:
            flag = False
            break
            sleepTime = random.randint(2,10)
            time.sleep(sleepTime)
            print(str(sleepTime) + ' seconds wait.')

    page += 1

f.close()
```

Comment: Suggest you use the popular [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) package instead of `urllib`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered this kind of issues when scrapping data from Yelp. It is hard to bypass such restrictions. I would suggest that you try the following.

1. Change your user agent. The current user agent seems to be for an iPhone. Use a valid one for a PC.
2. If the above works, but you are blocked after making a certain amount of page requests - take a look at StarCluster. You'll find a draft of the code under "4/13/2017 (UTEP CoBA 310 – CALC LAB #2)" at https://yangwangteaching.wordpress.com/data-science-meetup/

Comment: Thanks. I will try again.

Comment: Also try running from a new IP address if you are still getting 404 error after changing your user agent.